# 45 Degree Angle cut on divs

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to cut out the top right corner of most of my div elements on my site. These divs are all different sizes. I'm trying to find a responsive way of doing this. I ran into this site here: http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/ which allows you to cut out a custom polygon shape.

Here is what I have so far:

```css
div {
 width: 280px;
 height: 280px;
 background: #1e90ff;
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 9%, 89% 0%, 0% 0%);
clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 9%, 89% 0%, 0% 0%);
}

/* Center the demo */
html, body { height: 100%; }
body {
   background-image: url('http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/recycled_texture_background_by_sandeep_m-d6aeau9_PZ9chud.jpg');
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

My question is I'm trying to read these clippings and find out how to make the perfect 45 degree angle cut off the top right corner. As of right now this polygon was created by me freehand. And I'm trying to see what percentages I would need to use to make the perfect 45 degree angle cut from the top right.

With the solution I will be adding the cutoff to most of my divs, buttons, and images.

I found other ways of doing this on Stack Overflow using border-left and right with absolute position, but the problem is I need the div cutoff to be transparent because some of them have background images behind it.

Here is a JS Fiddle that's set up: https://jsfiddle.net/xyvz5z8m/1/

Comment: I believe it creates points so 0% 100% is bottom left, 100% 100% is bottom right and so on.. Just not sure how to convert it to a 45% degree angle. I'm not sure if this would be a math question?

Comment: Is the background your divs are sitting on a solid colour?

Comment: @Shaggy no not always, some of them are going to be background images. Which is why it was a little tougher to do this.

Comment: SVG would do this, CSS with bg image might with mix-blend-mode or background-blend-mode. if it is a matter of plain color, then a gradient will do just fine :)

Comment: @GCyrillus thanks for the info! Can you point me to the direction on how I can accomplish this? I've actually never used SVG before.

Comment: well i have no svg eample right now, but a quick one with mix-blend-mode .... http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EydRWP

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to do an exact 45 degree clip by using CSS calc, to work out the positions to clip from, instead of the percentages. e.g.

```
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 30px, calc(100% - 30px) 0%, 0% 0%);
clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 30px, calc(100% - 30px) 0%, 0% 0%);
```

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #1e90ff;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 30px, calc(100% - 30px) 0%, 0% 0%);
    clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 30px, calc(100% - 30px) 0%, 0% 0%);
  
    /* Resizing this div just to show that this will remain at 45 degrees */
    animation: resize 5s infinite; 
}

html, body {
    height: 100%; 
}

body {
    background: #ededed;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

@keyframes resize {
    0%     { width: 100px; height: 100px; }
    25%    { width: 50px; height: 100px; }
    50%    { width: 50px; height: 50px; }
    75%    { width: 150px; height: 50px; }
    100%   { width: 100px; height: 100px; }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

The key part being that we use pixel sizes for the positioning of the clipped area, and `calc(100% - 30px)` to get an exact position from the far side of the element, though bare in mind this may have very limited browser support.

Comment: ahh i see but with this solution I need a fix height and width correct? For example if I want to do this affect on a button it wont look the same.

Comment: @VinceMamba This requires that the cut off area is the same size yes, though potentially you could do something with calculating based on just one of width/height as a percentage. I'll have a look and see if I can update this.

Comment: that would be very helpful if you could! Thank you.

Comment: @VinceMamba Unfortunately, I can't see any way that this could be done so it's both 45 degrees and responsively sized to the element (using clip-path) It's not ideal, but you could have a couple of classes with different sized corners that you can apply to different elements.

Comment: yea might have to do that, or just approach this whole thing using a different method.